# Access to Application Support Directory on the device during development

Tags: ios, xcode

One can physically access to the app's Document Directory on the device using iTunes File Sharing.  What about the Application Support Directory?  (The same way if the app is on the simulator)

Anyway one can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/copy_app_data_from_sandbox.html

This should provide you with a package of all data within the App's sandbox

Comment: Chris, can anyone access this Application Support Directory after the app goes live? Also let me know if it is possible in Jail Broken phones?

Comment: If they have access to the device then you should assume they can get to the data. Is your question stemming from a security concern or feature?

Comment: It's from a security concern. I am saving some important data files into Application Support Directory assuming no one can access them... I thought Documents directory is way easier to access.